# Delete Custom Row In ListView

Tags: android

I have two classes that I'm working with. Contacts and CustomAdapter. In my Contacts Class I have an onActivityResult() method, which gets data from a different activity and places it in a Custom ListView using my CustomAdapter Class. The data gets added fine. Each row consists of a name, email, phone number AND a Button Widget. My question is, I would like to be able to press this Button and have that specific row be deleted. I've tried a number of different things but nothing seems to be working.

I placed the code below. If anyone has any suggestions on the best way to do this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

onActivityResult in Contacts Class:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");
            final String email = data.getStringExtra("email");
            //These are array lists declared earlier
            phoneNums.add(phone);
            names.add(name);
            emails.add(email);

            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Contacts.this,names,phoneNums,emails);
            contactList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

 contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    names.remove(position);
                    phoneNums.remove(position);
                    phoneNums.remove(position);

                    //This method is still not being recognized
                    contactList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()

                   //This one is but the app is crashing when I click on any of the rows

                    contactList.getAdapter().notify()
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter Entire Class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String>phoneNumbers;
private ArrayList<String>names;
private ArrayList<String>emails;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public CustomAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String>n,ArrayList<String>nums,ArrayList<String>e){
    context = c;
    phoneNumbers = nums;
    names = n;
    emails = e;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long)position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row,null);
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteButton);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
        TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
        TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);

        name.setText(names.get(position));
        phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
        email.setText(emails.get(position));

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //SHOULD I PLACE CODE TO DELETE THE ROW IN HERE?

            }
        });


    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need is one `List<>`to rule the size of you List (i believe yours is the `names`. For that, your `getItem(int position)` has to return `names.size()`. To delete a specific row, you just need to delete the index of `names` that you want, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter after that.

Comment: So my getItem method looks like this now....public Object getItem(int position) {return names.size();} Do you know how and where I would utilize this now? Back in the Contacts class or within the onClick in the getView method above?Thank you.

Comment: you dont need to use this method, it's used automatically by the adapter.

Comment: When you say "delete the index of names that you want", where would I place this code?

Comment: You can put this code on the click listener that you already defined. Delete the index, and call `this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I tried this in my onClick()     names.remove(position);notifyDataSetChanged(); This is only deleting my last row in the ListView, instead of the specific one that I click. What should I pass in the names.remove parameter instead? The position variable isn't quite working.

Comment: I think its easier to get the right row, if you put this code in the `onItemClickListener` of your view, becouse there the position you want is passed on the function.

Comment: The problem is that my onItemClickListener is in my Contacts Class and not my CustomAdapter Class.  (It comes right after my customAdapter is set) When I add notifyDataSetChanged(); It says that the method cannot be resolved

Comment: Thats correct, you have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter that you already set: `list.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I feel like I'm really close, I updated the code above to include the onItemClick method.  The contactList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() is still not getting recognized? I tried another method, contactList.getAdapter().notify(), but the app keeps crashing. Any ideas from looking at the code? I really appreciate the help

Comment: are you able to call the method on the `customAdapter` object?

Comment: Yeah, that works but it's only deleting the last entry again : /